# The number of solutions for a system of two linear equations in two variables over GF(2) could be

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I'm having problems understanding an answer to a  question.

Q. The number of solutions for a system of two linear equations in two variables over GF(2) could be

A. 0, 1, 2, or 4

I thought since the answer will be given in GF(2) the solutions can only be 0,1 hence the number of solutions can be 0,1, or 2

Comment: There are two variables. $(x,y)$ has four alternatives $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. The task is to check how many of those four can be solutions to a system of two linear equations.

Comment: so to my understanding a solution is a form of  (x,y) , then shouldn't the answer just be 4 @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Why would they **all** be solutions? If, for example the system is $x+y=1$; $x=0$, then there is only a single solution, namely $(0,1)$. The number of solutions surely depends on the system of equations.